# change my monitor display so as to fit to a square

Tags: linux, linux-mint

folks, my screen just got cracked, but there is a very small crack on the left corner. its like the contents on my screen towards the top left corner are invisible.

now each time i open a application i have to resize it so that the contents are all visible.

consider this for example....
consider my screen as a rectangle. now the dimensions of this rectangle are approx 20 X 10 cm. now the top left corner of rectangle is spoilt. hence i want the first 6 cms of my screen to display nothing whereas the rest of the screen shows the other applications.

```
--------------------
| B  | all content |
| L  |   here      |
| A  |             |
| N  |             |
| K  |             |
|    |             |
|    |             |
--------------------
```

operating system is linux mint.

Comment: This should be migrated to SuperUser

Comment: superuser ??? @heltonbiker

Comment: Sorry, it's another StackExchange site: http://superuser.com/ . And there's also http://askubuntu.com/